# Spherical Cardioid

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Calculate the mass of the apple-shaped solid bounded by the rotated cardioid $\rho  = R(1 - \cos \varphi )$ (in spherical coordinates), if the density at distance $\rho $ from the origin is given by $\delta (\rho ,\varphi ,\theta ) = {\delta _0} \cdot \frac{\rho }{R}$.

[image]

**My solution:**

By using spherical coordinates we have $$x = \rho \sin \theta \cos \varphi ,\,\,\,\,\,y = \rho \sin \theta \sin \varphi ,\,\,\,\,\,z = \rho \cos \theta $$

\begin{equation} \notag
\begin{split}
  m &= \iiint\limits_E {\delta (\rho ,\varphi ,\theta )\,dV = \int\limits_0^{2\pi } {\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {\int\limits_0^{R(1 - \cos \varphi )} {{\delta _0} \cdot \frac{\rho }{R}\,{\rho ^2}\sin \varphi \,\,d\rho \,d} } } }\varphi \,d\theta \\
   &= \frac{{{\delta _0}}}{R}\int\limits_0^{2\pi } {\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {\sin \varphi \int\limits_0^{R(1 - \cos \varphi )} {\,\,{\rho ^3}\,d\rho \,d} } } \varphi \,d\theta  = \frac{{{\delta _0}{R^3}}}{4}\int\limits_0^{2\pi } {\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {\sin \varphi  \cdot {{\left( {1 - \cos \varphi } \right)}^4}} \,d} \varphi \,d\theta \\
   &= \frac{{{\delta _0}{R^3}}}{{20}}\int\limits_0^{2\pi } {d\theta }  = \frac{{{\delta _0}{R^3}}}{{20}} \cdot 2\pi  = \frac{1}{{10}}\pi {R^3}{\delta _0} \\ 
\end{split}
\end{equation}

**Comments:**

I'm not sure if i got the correct limits for $\varphi $. Should it be from 0 to $\frac{\pi }{2}$ or from 0 to $\pi $?

Comment: Looks like it should be $0$ to $\pi$? I can't imagine how else you'd get a point at $\rho=2R$?

Comment: I think you are right.